# extract-text-webpack-plugin fails: self is not defined

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-2

I am trying to setup extract-text-webpack-plugin, but it fails with

```
ERROR in ./src/css/app.css
Module build failed: ReferenceError: self is not defined
    at /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/style-loader/index.js!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--1-3!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/src/css/app.css:103:30
    at /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/style-loader/index.js!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--1-3!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/src/css/app.css:98:47
    at module.exports.module.exports (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/style-loader/index.js!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--1-3!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/src/css/app.css:123:68)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/style-loader/index.js!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--1-3!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/src/css/app.css:2526:36)
    at __webpack_require__ (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/style-loader/index.js!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--1-3!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/src/css/app.css:21:30)
    at /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/style-loader/index.js!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--1-3!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/src/css/app.css:67:18
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/style-loader/index.js!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--1-3!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/src/css/app.css:70:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.exec (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:98:6)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js:112:21)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:280:10)
    at /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:480:13
    at next (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:138:11)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js:93:4)
    at next (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/tapable/lib/Tapable.js:140:14)
    at Compiler.<anonymous> (/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/webpack/lib/CachePlugin.js:62:5)

ERROR in /home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/extract-text-webpack-plugin/loader.js??ref--1-0!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/style-loader/index.js!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/style-loader/index.js!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--1-3!/home/jiewmeng/Dropbox/finances-frontend/src/css/app.css doesn't export content
```

Whats wrong here? My `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require("path")
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin")
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")

const context = path.resolve(__dirname, "src")

module.exports = {
  context,
  entry: "./js/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build/js"),
    filename: "index.js"
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        options: {
          plugins: [
            [
              "react-css-modules",
              {
                context
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: [
            "style-loader",
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                modules: true,
                importLoaders: 1,
                localIdentName: "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }
          ]
        })
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./index.html",
      filename: "index.html",
      inject: "body"
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("app.css")
  ],
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
  }
}
```

## UPDATE: Fixed but why?

I found my mistake is I should pass an object to the `use` in `ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ use })` like below instead of the array I am using above but why?

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        fallback: "style-loader",
        use: { // pass object instead of array, omiting the `style-loader` part but why? 
          loader: "css-loader",
          options: {
            modules: true,
            importLoaders: 1,
            localIdentName: "[path]___[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]",
            sourceMap: true
          }
        }
      })
    }
  ]
},
```

Comment: Both Webpack two configs on my projects pass an Array into the `use` key for ExtractTextPlugin, so I don't think that is the issue (the official docs also say arrays are okay). I think actually it is `style-loader` that is causing the issue. I've commonly seen it as the fallback, but never in the main set of loaders.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it is not related to usage of array, but the usage `style-loader`.

I meet the same problem, but with postcss, and I solved by change

```
module: {
  rules: [
    use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', {
      loader: 'postcss-loader',
      options: ...
    }],
  ]
},
```

into

```
module: {
  rules: [
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: ['css-loader', {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: ...
      }]
    }),
  ]
},
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped a very similar problem I was having with `webfonts-loader` instead of `postcss-loader` :-)